# divisibility by $10^6$ for $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the smallest number $n$ for 
$n\cdot(n+4)\cdot(n+8)\cdot(n+12)\cdot(n+16)$ is divisible by $10^6$.

I have found obvious solution for $n=999984$. Is it correct?

Comment: You are right that for that $n$ the product is divisible by $10^6$, but it's not the lowest. For instance, what about $n=499\,984$? Can you see why that also works? Can you guess other, smaller numbers that also work?

Comment: For that product to be divisible by $10^6$ it needs to be divisible by $5^6$ and $2^6$. Exactly one of the factors is divisible by five (you prove that!), so that factor also needs to be divisible by $5^6$. For the product to be even, all the factors need to be even, and as there are only five of them one of them has to be divisible by four. You take it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have divisibility be $10^6$, we need divisibility by $2^6$ and $5^6$. For the former, we need that at least one of the five factors is a multiple of $4$ - but then all factors are, so for divisibility by $2^6$ it is necessary and sufficient to have $4\mid n$.
To have divisibility by $5^6$, at least one of the five factors must be divisible by $25$ - but then none of the others is even divisible by $5$. Hence that one factor must already be divisible by $5^6=15625$. As we saw previously, this one factor must even be divisible by $2^25^6$. And $n$ is smallest when this happens to the biggest factor, so $$n=2^25^6-16 =62484.$$